# How to create an authentication and authorization system in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization

I am creating a Video Platform with a video player and library. I am storing the videos in google storage bucket and setting the permissions on each video object, who can access the videos in the bucket.
When a user login, I want to display the videos only he has access to.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to authenticate your user. You can use [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform) for this. It's very very close to Firebase Auth.

Then, when an authenticated user upload a video, you have to

- Store it into Cloud Storage
- Write in a database (Firestore is perfect for this) the link between the user email and the file stored into Cloud Storage

Finally, when the user look for their video, you request firestore with the user email, and you have the list of all the Cloud Storage blob that belong to their.